# Is there any scriptural precedent for praying in the second person (using "you")? Is this from outside Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, gods, sanskrit, other-religions, prayer

In modern times, when people pray, they do it overwhelmingly in the second person. In scriptures, however, the third person (or no person) is overwhelmingly the person the prayers are in, and I have found even the first person used more than the second person. I have found this trend to continue even during historical prayers beyond scripture.

Does anyone know a movement that started this praying in second person thing? When did this trend historically start? What ideology started this trend? Should prayers in the second person be avoided? Is there any scripture that states the supremacy of the third person or no person for the majority of prayers? Is this a foreign concept from other religions? Do other religions pray in the second person? I heard the Lord's prayer from Christianity in it's original language Aramaic is not in the second person, so did it happen after this, in Islam or Sikhism? Does the Quran or Guru Granth Sahib sanction this?